# Is this "truncating" matrix function well known?

Tags: matrices, notation

I'm working with a kind of "truncating" matrix function $\tau_r:M_{n\times n}\to M_{n\times r}$, where $r\leq n$, defined by $\tau_r(A)=B$, where $b_{ij}=a_{ij}$ for $j\leq r$.

Is this a well known function in matrix theory, or is there a similar one I could use, without having to define my own function $\tau$ ? Or maybe there exists a widely used notation instead ?

Comment: It's a projection $\text{Mat}_{n \times n} \to \text{Mat}_{n \times r}$ - it might be more natural to refer to it as $\pi_r$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: So maybe I could say "... define the projection $\pi_r:M_{n\times n}\to M_{n\times r}$ where $r\leq n$..." without having to mention how the function is defined due to the presence of the word "projection" in the definition statement.

Comment: I would still make sure to define it properly - it never hurts to err on the side of more-clear rather than less-clear.

Comment: You mean taking the *submatrix*? Often it is done by $A(I,J)$ where $I$ and $J$ are the sets of subindices for the extraction. But in your case it is very special  submatrix, maybe easier with a simpler notation.

Comment: Good point ! Thanks. I think using $\pi_r$ would be more natural.

Comment: @picasso that would not necessarily be enough, since it's not obvious just from that which columns are deleted. If you say "define the map $\pi_r:M_{n\times n}\to M_{n\times r}$ for $r\leq n$ by projecting onto the first $r$ columns", or something along those lines, then you should be good to go.

Comment: If it is a repeated operation you are dealing with, I would call it $A_r$ to refer to the submatrix made of the first $r$ columns of $A$  (if there is no confusion with other notations in the same text).

Comment: Talking about projections may be mistaken as a projection on the *image subspace* spanned by the first $r$ columns, should be careful here. I would not use the word projection, because here you have a very simple operation, and to use an advanced terminology does not help understanding and make the tings sound more complex than they are.

Comment: Maybe my original definition in the question is fine then?

Comment: Call it truncation as you did, it is good enough, simple and clear.

Comment: Ok, thanks all. I think I'll stick with my $\tau$ definition. As A.G. says, submatrix is good, but my submatrix is very special so the usual notation may be overkill. I don't think $A_r$ would be great because my matrices can be made up many multiplications, so it may be confusing. I like the idea of projection, but projections have a huge theory surrounding them and I don't intend to use that where $\tau$ is concerned. I may be using projections later on, so this might also cause confusion if mixing notation. Interesting to be reminded of submatrices and projections in this context though !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't encountered such truncating function, but you're basically getting a submatrix of a matrix. So let me say the following.

In Horn & Johnson's Matrix Analysis, they introduced the notation: Given $A\in M_{n}$, if $\alpha,\beta\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then $A[\alpha, \beta]$ denotes the submatrix of entries that lie in the rows of $A$ indexed by $\alpha$ and the columns indexed by $\beta$.

You might want to write your matrix as $A[\{1,\ldots, n\}, \{1,\ldots, r\}]$. It's pretty tedious to write this though. It doesn't hurt to introduce some notation like $A(n,r)$ or $A_r$ if you have to use it repeatedly.